# detect rdp ram remotely with FreeRDP without x server (x11)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, rdp, windows-command-prompt

i've installed freerdp on my ubuntu vps i got it from digital ocean
after few problems regarding the x server problem and freerdp can't work without x server i able to configure it to check the credintal of rdp without x server
this command `xfreerdp /cert-ignore +auth-only /v:"iprdp:3389" /u:"username" /p:"password"`

and it works good now all i want is how to detect rdp ram with only command line like this without x-server or any idea like this to remotely know rdp ram
please notice that rdp i try to connect to is windows server 2012 r2 and some rdps like that upto windows server 2019

Comment: What do you mean by "rdp ram"? If you are going to moninor remote server RAM usage/free, RDP is certainly not the right way to do it. Install e.g. openssh on the server (yes, windows) and connect via ssh and ask using commandline tools, perhaps powershell. Also notice you can run a virtual X server like Xvnc, so freerdp could still be run on the VPS. You can see the screen it is drawing into using a vnc client.

Comment: i mean the rdp ram which is included in any rdp like processor type and ram gb amount